Multitenancy in Shopify remix app with MongoDb
I am looking to implement multitenancy in a Remix Shopify app. My goal is for each store to have its own database, while a main database only holding store and session details.
When a store installs the app, I want to dynamically create a database and tables specific to that store.
I have added below function to configure Prisma to work with a store-specific database. Can anyone suggest the best approach or provide insights on handling this setup effectively?
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  if (!global.prisma) {
    global.prisma = new PrismaClient();
  }
}

const prisma = global.prisma || new PrismaClient();

export function prismaStore(storeDomain) {
  if (!storeDomain) {
    throw new Error("Store domain is required to create a database connection.");
  }

  const baseUrl = process.env.DATABASE_TENENCEY_URL;

  if (!baseUrl) {
    throw new Error("DATABASE_TENENCEY_URL is not defined in the environment variables.");
  }

  const dbUrl = baseUrl.replace("STOREDB", storeDomain);

  return new PrismaClient({
    datasources: {
      db: {
        url: dbUrl,
      },
    },
  });
}

export default prisma;

